# Problem with create database in docker-compose / postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    container_name: "postgres"
    image: postgres:14
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB:database
    ports:
      -   "127.0.0.1:5434:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Docker don't create database for this container, what is wrong?

Comment: What error message did it give?

Comment: In the environment variable setting, you have a colon and not an equals sign; the third line should be `POSTGRES_DB=database`.  Does fixing that address your problem?

Answer (score 0):

**IF IT IS NOT AN ISSUE WITH TYPO** here `- POSTGRES_DB:database` instead of `- POSTGRES_DB=database`

Did you ever start the Postgres container without specifying the user and database?

This could happen when the docker volume had already stored data from previous runs, where you didn't set the user and DB, then later runs with different env variables will not change the users. **That is only done on the first initialization**.

So you need to run

```
docker volume prune
```

There is already a closed issue on GitHub about that, see: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/453